# multiply all columns of DataFrame with a rows of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames:

df1

```
DT   D1   D2
0   1.0  0.50
```

df2

```
DT             D1        D2
C_Step                     
UNKNOWN  0.202899  0.325581
fair     0.253623  0.244186
good     0.289855  0.186047
poor     0.253623  0.244186
```

How I can multiply first row of df1 with all rows of df2.

desired DataFrame is:

```
DT             D1        D2
C_Step                     
UNKNOWN  0.202899  0.162790
fair     0.253623  0.122092
good     0.289855  0.093023
poor     0.253623  0.122093
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check with `mul` , before that you need also convert df1 to `Series`

```
df2.mul(df1.loc[0],axis=1)
               D1        D2
DT                         
UNKNOWN  0.202899  0.162791
fair     0.253623  0.122093
good     0.289855  0.093023
poor     0.253623  0.122093
```